# grunt.js throws error when using grunt-vows

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, vows

I'm using grunt-vows (https://github.com/CMTegner/grunt-vows) in the following gruntfile:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {  
  // Project configuration.  
  grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-vows");  
  grunt.initConfig({  
    vows: {  
      all: {  
        options: {  
          reporter: "spec",  
          verbose: true,  
          silent: false,  
          colors: true,  
          isolate: false,  
          coverage: "json"  
        },  
        src: ["test/*.js"]  
      }  
    }  
  });  
  // Default task.  
  grunt.registerTask('default', 'vows');  
};
```

and getting the following error when I run `grunt`:
`TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'options'`
`at Object.<anonymous> (/home/dan/playlist/node_modules/grunt-vows/tasks/vows.js:32:33)`
`at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt/task.js:109:15)`
`at Object.thisTask.fn (/usr/lib/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt/task.js:58:16)`

I'm confident that I've made a simple mistake somewhere, does anything look out of place in the gruntfile?

Thanks in advance,
Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this are some compatibilty issues with your local installed grunt and this module!

if you have grunt 0.3.x installed (what i think is your problem) you could use an older version of this plugin (should be grunt-vows@0.3.1 or older).

probably the best thing you can do is upgrade your local installed grunt to 0.4.0 (see the migration guide here: http://gruntjs.com/upgrading-from-0.3-to-0.4), because you will run into this issue a lot if you want to include new grunt-plugins.

of course this will add some additional work in already existing gruntfiles

Comment: Exactly the issue :) Thanks